# Designing a marker pin for google map

Tags: gui-design, guidelines, image, maps

A marker that is placed on a googlemap as a overlay needs to be designed so that the pin point lies exactly on the point that you specify to place it during coding.

Check the example below, the bubble had to be rotated to be placed so that it represents the exact point on the map.

My question is, are there any rules, guidelines available to design the markers so that I dont have to iterate over trial and error multiple times before finding the perfect marker ?

[image]

Comment: Seems more like programming problem to me. What is the user interface or interaction angle here?

Comment: Personally, I think the marker in your example looks like it's highlighting an area rather than pointing to an exact location.

Comment: Its not a programming problem. I need to know how to design the graphic so that I point to the exact location. What should be my ratio of pointer location to the width of the graphic background. This is a  purely user interface question and has no place on any stackexchange site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bubble *doesn't* have to point at the exact place - it can point at the *pin* that marks the place.

Rectangular bubbles (rounded corners included) are much more adaptable to the content within than elliptical bubbles, and are much easier to position the pointer on any part of any edge.

Is there anything wrong with what Google Maps does already:

Eg: On Desktop:

[image]

Also note how with the extra space available on desktop they distance the bubble via a thin pointer so you can see more of the area around the point of interest.

And on mobile:

[image]

Comment: This is a interesting angle to it. Yes, I agree that I can use standard google markers and bubbles.